# How to change the "SHOP BY Shopping options" price ranges when viewing a category on the front page?

Tags: shopping-cart

When I click on any category - it shows the SHOP BY Shopping Options box on the left and gives several Price range options like:

$0.00 - $99.99 (46)  
$100.00 and above (14)

How can I customize it? I want to setup something like this:

$0.00 - $50 
$50 - $100 
$100 and above

Thanks for any suggestions! ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `system => configuration`
select `Catalog` from left under `Catalog menu`

Select `Layered Navigation`.
Change the `price navigation step calculation` there.